# Psalm of retaliation

Tags: tehilim-psalms

once a rabbi pointed me out to a Psalm sounding like "You [G-d] are wicked to the wicked" and so on, but I can't recall what it was.

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Manaus, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thank you for your post.  With a little thought, someone can figure out what the question is here, but it's not actually written in the form of a question.  Also, we generally frown upon questions posed as, "I'm thinking of something but I don't know what; can you tell me what it is?" See [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) for more.

Comment: This appears to be a ["Guessing Game"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) question.

Comment: T'motet rasha ra'a?

Comment: [94](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A6%D7%93)?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps psalm [9](http://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.9) or [37](http://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.37)?

Psalm 9:

> 1 For the Leader; upon Muthlabben. A Psalm of David. 2 I will give thanks unto the LORD with my whole heart; I will tell of all Thy marvellous works. 3 I will be glad and exult in Thee; I will sing praise to Thy name, O Most High: 4 When mine enemies are turned back, They stumble and perish at Thy presence; 5 For Thou hast maintained my right and my cause; Thou sattest upon the throne as the righteous Judge. 6 **Thou hast rebuked the nations, Thou hast destroyed the wicked, Thou hast blotted out their name for ever and ever.** 7 O thou enemy, the waste places are come to an end for ever; And the cities which thou didst uproot, Their very memorial is perished. 8 But the LORD is enthroned for ever; He hath established His throne for judgment. 9 And He will judge the world in righteousness, He will minister judgment to the peoples with equity. 10 The LORD also will be a high tower for the oppressed, A high tower in times of trouble; 11 And they that know Thy name will put their trust in Thee; For thou, LORD, hast not forsaken them that seek Thee. 12 Sing praises to the LORD, who dwelleth in Zion; Declare among the peoples His doings. 13 For He that avengeth blood hath remembered them; He hath not forgotten the cry of the humble. 14 Be gracious unto me, O LORD, Behold mine affliction at the hands of them that hate me; Thou that liftest me up from the gates of death; 15 That I may tell of all Thy praise in the gates of the daughter of Zion, That I may rejoice in Thy salvation. 16 The nations are sunk down in the pit that they made; In the net which they hid is their own foot taken. 17 The LORD hath made Himself known, He hath executed judgment, The wicked is snared in the work of his own hands. Higgaion. Selah 18 The wicked shall return to the nether-world, Even all the nations that forget God. 19 For the needy shall not alway be forgotten, Nor the expectation of the poor perish for ever. 20 Arise, O LORD, let not man prevail; Let the nations be judged in Thy sight. 21 Set terror over them, O LORD; Let the nations know they are but men. Selah

Psalm 37:

> [A Psalm] of David. Fret not thyself because of evil-doers, Neither be thou envious against them that work unrighteousness. 2 **For they shall soon wither like the grass, And fade as the green herb.** 3 Trust in the LORD, and do good; Dwell in the land, and cherish faithfulness. 4 So shalt thou delight thyself in the LORD; And He shall give thee the petitions of thy heart. 5 Commit thy way unto the LORD; Trust also in Him, and He will bring it to pass. 6 And He will make thy righteous-ness to go forth as the light, And thy right as the noonday. 7 Resign thyself unto the LORD, and wait patiently for Him; Fret not thyself because of him who prospereth in his way, Because of the man who bringeth wicked devices to pass. 8 Cease from anger, and forsake wrath; Fret not thyself, it tendeth only to evil-doing. 9 For evil-doers shall be cut off; But those that wait for the LORD, they shall inherit the land. 10 And yet a little while, and the wicked is no more; Yea, thou shalt look well at his place, and he is not. 11 But the humble shall inherit the land, And delight themselves in the abundance of peace. 12 The wicked plotteth against the righteous, And gnasheth at him with his teeth. 13 The Lord doth laugh at him; For He seeth that his day is coming. 14 The wicked have drawn out the sword, and have bent their bow; To cast down the poor and needy, To slay such as are upright in the way; 15 Their sword shall enter into their own heart, And their bows shall be broken. 16 Better is a little that the righteous hath Than the abundance of many wicked. 17 For the arms of the wicked shall be broken; But the LORD upholdeth the righteous. 18 The LORD knoweth the days of them that are wholehearted; And their inheritance shall be for ever. 19 They shall not be ashamed in the time of evil; And in the days of famine they shall be satisfied. 20 For the wicked shall perish, And the enemies of the LORD shall be as the fat of lambs— They shall pass away in smoke, they shall pass away. . 21 The wicked borroweth, and payeth not; But the righteous dealeth graciously, and giveth. 22 For such as are blessed of Him shall inherit the land; And they that are cursed of Him shall be cut off. 23 It is of the LORD that a man's goings are established; And He delighted in his way. 24 Though he fall, he shall not be utterly cast down; For the LORD upholdeth his hand. 25 I have been young, and now am old; Yet have I not seen the righteous forsaken, Nor his seed begging bread. 26 All the day long he dealeth graciously, and lendeth; And his seed is blessed. 27 Depart from evil, and do good; And dwell for evermore. 28 For the LORD loveth justice, And forsaketh not His saints; They are preserved for ever; But the seed of the wicked shall be cut off. 29 The righteous shall inherit the land, And dwell therein for ever. 30 The mouth of the righteous uttereth wisdom, And his tongue speaketh justice. 31 The law of his God is in his heart; None of his steps slide. 32 The wicked watcheth the righteous, And seeketh to slay him. 33 The LORD will not leave him in his hand, Nor suffer him to be condemned when he is judged. 34 Wait for the LORD, and keep His way, And He will exalt thee to inherit the land; When the wicked are cut off, thou shalt see it. 35 I have seen the wicked in great power, And spreading himself like a leafy tree in its native soil. 36 But one passed by, and, lo, he was not; Yea, I sought him, but he could not be found. 37 Mark the man of integrity, and behold the upright; For there is a future for the man of peace. 38 But transgressors shall be destroyed together; The future of the wicked shall be cut off. 39 But the salvation of the righteous is of the LORD; He is their stronghold in the time of trouble. 40 And the LORD helpeth them, and delivereth them; He delivereth them from the wicked, and saveth them, Because they have taken refuge in Him.

Answer (score 0):

While not a psalm, the phrase you remember sounds like a line from the medieval hymn [Yigdal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yigdal), based on Maimonides' 13 Principles. The eleventh line reads:

> גּוֹמֵל לְאִישׁ חֶסֶד (חָסִיד) כְּמִפְעָלוֹ
>
> נוֹתֵּן (יִתֵּן) לְרָשָׁע רָע כְּרִשְׁעָתוֹ
>
> G!d rewards one with kindness (or: a kind one) according to their actions /
>
> G!d deals evil on the wicked according to their wickedness.